# How to change the value of Dropdown dynamically and make it uneditable

Tags: jquery

I have got a drop down as

```
<select id="BrandNames">
<option value="3000">General</option>
<option value="3001">KFC</option>
<option value="3002">Chutneys</option>
</select>
```

Once forming the drodown successfully

I am trying to change its value , this way

```
var setthisvalue = 'KFC' ;

$("#BrandNames").val(setthisvalue);
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/y9cyag0n/1/

This is not setting the value of combobox ?

My requirement is that i need to set the value of created combobox based on the **setthisvalue** Value and after that the combobox shouldn't be **editable** ??

Could anybody please let me know why it isn't setting the value ??

Comment: "KFC" is not value! The value is "3001".

Comment: Have no idea of what you are asking but you are trying to set the value for `select` tag and not the `option` tag, inorder to replace 3001 to kfc you need to target `option` tag like `$('$BrandNames option:nth-child(2)').val(setthisvalue);`

Comment: Also how your select box is even editable by anyone? If you are trying to stop the edits via console then forget it, even disabling or making the options readonly won't prevent the users to alter the values via console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the text not the value, you can find the right option by text, and use that to set the value and then disable the dropdown:

```
var value = 'KFC' ;

var option = $("#BrandNames option").filter(function(){
   return $(this).text() == value; 
});
$("#BrandNames").val(option.val()).prop('disabled',true);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9cyag0n/3/

Comment: Yes. This is the way. `:contains` will match even partial strings.

Answer (score 1):

Because "KFC" is not a value; the corresponding value is "3001".

```
$("#BrandNames").val('3001').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the value to "KFC" which is not the value of the `option`. The value is "3001".

So, you need to set it to the proper value.

On the other hand, if all you have is the text string and you want to set the value based on that string, then you need to find the string in the options and use the found value to set.

Once done, you can set the "disabled" property to "true", to disable the select.

***Snippet***:

```js
var value = 'KFC' ;
var $opt = $("#BrandNames").children(":contains(" + value + ")");
$("#BrandNames").val($opt.val());
$("#BrandNames").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="BrandNames">
  <option value="3000">General</option>
  <option value="3001">KFC</option>
  <option value="3002">Chutneys</option>
</select>
```

***Note***: This is just an idea. Be warned that if there are multiple options with similar text, then you need to find workarounds. Also, note that `:contains` is not exact match, it literally means "*contains*" i.e. even if part of the string matches. Ideally you should be doing a `filter` on options.

.

Comment: I [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9cyag0n/4/) to demonstrate the danger you specified.

Comment: @Jamiec: Yes, I realized that and that's why put in the disclaimer.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#BrandNames option:contains('"+ value +"')").prop('selected', true).parent().prop('disabled', true);
```

See[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9cyag0n/2/)

Comment: @PreethiJain - be careful using `contains`, if you're looking for `ABC` but the option `ABCDEFG` is first you'll find the wrong one. For an exact match see my answer. EG: http://jsfiddle.net/y9cyag0n/4/

Comment: @Jamiec you are right but as you saw the OP requirement it can go that way .. may be he decided to use it in keyup event or something like that ..  .anyway. thanks for that :)